# How to create a list of Django Forms -- with different HTML names so we can retrieve them easily?

Tags: html, django, django-forms

In a table, each row contains an ID number and a dropdown. I want the user to choose a value in each row's dropdown, and then submit all that and display it on the next page. On the next page I call `request.POST.get()` so each dropdown needs to have a unique HTML name.

Currently I have the following which works for displaying the info:

```py
class Dropdown(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, mylistTuples):
        super(Dropdown,self).__init__()
        self.fields['dropdown'] = forms.CharField(label="", widget=forms.Select(choices=mylistTuples))
    dropdown = forms.CharField()
```

The HTML output of that is:

```html
<tbody >
  <tr class="even">
    <td >item1</td>
    <td ><p> <select name="dropdown" id="id_dropdown">
      <option value="option1">option1</option>
      <option value="option2">option2</option>
    </select></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td >item2</td>
    <td ><p> <select name="dropdown" id="id_dropdown">
      <option value="option1">option1</option>
      <option value="option2">option2</option>
    </select></p></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

which doesn't allow me to retrieve the different `dropdown`s. `request.POST.get("dropdown")` only retrieves the last one!

I think I want something like the following, but I don't quite understand how the `self.fields['name']` relates to the variable `name`.

```py
class Dropdown(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, mylistTuples, my_id):
        super(Dropdown,self).__init__()
        self.fields['dropdown_'+my_id] = forms.CharField(label="", widget=forms.Select(choices=mylistTuples))
    dropdown?? = forms.CharField()
```

I also tried the following without success (`self` is not defined outside the `__init__` function apparently):

```py
class Dropdown(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, mylistTuples, my_id):
        super(Dropdown,self).__init__()
        self.fields['dropdown_'+my_id] = forms.CharField(label="", widget=forms.Select(choices=mylistTuples))
        self.my_id = my_id
    globals()['dropdown_'+self.my_id] = forms.CharField()
```

In the next page's view, `request.POST.items()` will allow me to loop through my results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to make it work, but I don't know if that's the most elegant way.
In my form definition, I store the name of the dropdown in a global variable (`dd_id`):

```py
class Dropdown(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, mylistTuples, my_id):
        super(Dropdown,self).__init__()
        global dd_id
        dd_id = 'dropdown_' + my_id
        self.fields[dd_id] = forms.CharField(label="", widget=forms.Select(choices=mylistTuples))
    globals()['dd_id'] = forms.CharField()
```

That creates the HTML output I was looking for, with personalized `name` and `id` fields.